# How to determine number of elements that are in a array in C

Tags: c, arrays

i'm new learning the C Languange.

I want to know the number of elements that are in a array for example

```
int MyArray[80] = {50, 845, 584};
n = sizeof(MyArray)/sizeof(MyArray[0]); // This will give me 80.
```

But I only want the number of elements that are inside of {}, As i initialized above it has 3 elements (50, 845, 584), so how do i count them by code?

Another question:

How do i create an empty array so i can add elements by myself and print all elements with a for loop, I've tried this:

```
int i;
int MyArray[80] = {};
MyArray[0] = 50;
MyArray[1] = 584;
MyArray[2] = 784;

for(i=0; i<=sizeof(MyArray); i++){

printf("Array Element[%d] is: %d", i, MyArray[i]);

}
```

But this doesn't seem to work, any help? Thanks

EDIT: i fixed it by doing the following code found in another post:

```
#include <stdio.h>

 #define NUM_ELEMS(a) (sizeof(a)/sizeof 0[a]) 

main() { int i; int numbers[] = {2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 85}; 

int AllElements = NUM_ELEMS(numbers);

 for(i=0; i<AllElements; i++){ 

printf("Element[%d] in array is: %d \n", i, numbers[i]); 

}

 }
```

Comment: i am sorry, but you need to remember yourself, using a variable.

Comment: You can't unless you maintain a variable to know the last occupied spot

Comment: However, i fixed it by doing the following code found in another post: #include <stdio.h>
#define NUM_ELEMS(a) (sizeof(a)/sizeof 0[a])
main()
{
    int i;
 int numbers[] = {2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 85};
 int AllElements = NUM_ELEMS(numbers);
 
 for(i=0; i<AllElements; i++){
  
  printf("Element[%d] in array is: %d \n", i, numbers[i]);
  
 }
 
 
} //Thanks anyways

Comment: Your alternative solution is very different because in your original you specify the size of the array (80) and in the second you don't.  If you don't need all 80 elements, don't specify the size.  If you do need all 80 elements, you can't complain when `sizeof()` tells you '80 integers worth'.

Comment: Please don't ask several questions in one go. too broad.

Answer (score 4):

If you initialize an array with fewer elements than the array is declared to hold, the remaining elements will be default-initialized. For integers, this means that they will be zeroed.

Assuming you have no zeroes in your initialization list, then, you can check how long the initialization list was by checking for the first zero in the array (up to the length of the array).

Alternately, if the array size should just be constant, you should specify the size as `[]`, which makes it exactly as long as the initialization list and no longer.

Answer (score 1):

> I only want the number of elements that are inside of {}

Try

```
 size_t n = sizeof (int[]){50, 845, 584} / sizeof (int);
```

Comment: It's upside-down anyway.

Answer (score 0):

An ugly way using the preprocessor:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define NARGS_SEQ(_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7,_8,N,...) N
#define NARGS(...) NARGS_SEQ(__VA_ARGS__, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1)

#define init_array(arr, ...) NARGS(__VA_ARGS__); arr = {__VA_ARGS__}

int main(void)
{
    int n = init_array(int my_array[80], 50, 845, 584);

    printf("%d\n", n);
    return 0;
}
```

Is expanded to:

```
int main(void)
{
 int n = 3; int my_array[80] = {50, 845, 584};

 printf("%d\n", n);
 return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
3
```

Note that this version is limited to `N` elements in the initializer.